# pdo utf8 encoding data fetching problems

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I know this aurgement was discussed several times but no one solutions or workarounds works for me :(

I'm using a pdo driver to querying a db on my server.
This is the connection:

```
        new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*******',
            '****', '*****', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

The option `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8` Already solves a lot of problems before, and I've found it as possible solution as string's econding problems.

But my output is still "dirty" and the operation of `json_encode()` (next operation to will after the data extraction) over some strings data fail without any chance to fix it, even with some extra options don't solve the problem!

The problem is from how the data are extracted from the db, even a `var_Dump()` of all the data fetched show how strings are corrupeted, this is an example of a field printed by a var_dump of the query result:

```
Zup2 Zuppa Ãˆ composta da diverse qualitÃ  di pesce, spesso quello cosiddetto "povero"
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: php version is 5.5.9, and the data on the db are well encoded

Comment: How should it look like?

Comment: It's possible the data is already corrupted in database. How did you get it in?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/). It's way too ambiguous and broad where exactly what problem is happening here.

Comment: the corrisponding string of the example taken from the db is:`È composta da diverse qualità di pesce, spesso quello cosiddetto "povero"`

Comment: @deceze yes i've already seen those links and i didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: setting `<meta charset="UTF-8">`   on the visualization pages seem to work for now...but is just an alternative workaround i guess